# Return true or false on SAS pattern match

Tags: regex, sas

Is it possible inside of a SAS macro to return true or false on matching a pattern.

I have a field where some rows will contain a string like

`word_1234_abc123`

Where word won't change, 1234 can be any number, and abc123 can be any three letters followed by any three numbers.

Is it possible to return true if a string matches that pattern?

I was looking at rxparse but that doesn't seem to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you needed?

```
rx = prxparse('^word_\d{4}_\w{3}\d{3}$');
if prxmatch(rx, string1) then return true;
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on RegExr**](http://regexr.com/3d3dh)</kbd>

---

How it works:

```
^        # String starts with ...
word_    # word_
\d{4}    # 4 Digits
_        # _ (Underscore)
 \w{3}   # 3 Letters
\d{3}    # 3 Digits
$        # ... String ends with
```

Comment: Thank you, and thanks for the explanation at the bottom

Comment: @MichaelStClair No Problem! If this answered your question, would you mind accepting it (press the tick underneath the voting buttons)? Thanks!

Comment: I will, it doesn't let you for a short time after the question is asked

Comment: @MichaelStClair Oh yeah, I forgot about that, thanks!